# Importing data from Excel into SQL Server that has a different design in the template in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am developing a system that will import and export a data from Excel into a SQL Server database. I already done in exporting, my problem is in importing the template that I will import is different template that I exported. I know the code about importing because I learned it in google, but in my problem is, I can't get what I need. So allow me to show a screenshot about the template in my Excel.

[image]

That's the template, and my database design is like this:

[image]

So the PODATE and PORECEIVEDDATE there in database is equal to the PO DATE below in Excel and DELIVERYDATE is equal to ETD in Excel.

As of now I have a code here that will get only the above template and it will not get the whole data in Excel.

Here is my code:

```
public void ImportDataFromExcel(string excelFilePath)
{
        string ssqltable = "tmp_100_POEntry_SF_sample";
        //string myexceldataquery = "select PONO,PODATE,PORECEIVEDDATE,DELIVERYDATE,PARTCODE,QUANTITY,UNITCOST,TOTALAMOUNT,STOCKS,INCHARGE,CLIENT from [Sheet1$]";
        string myexceldataquery = "select [PO NO],[PART CODE],QUANTITY,[UNIT COST],[TOTAL AMOUNT],STOCKS,[IN CHARGE],CLIENT from [Sheet1$]";

        try
        {
            string sexcelconnectionstring = @"provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=" + excelFilePath +
            ";extended properties=" + "\"excel 8.0;hdr=yes;\"";

            string sclearsql = "delete from " + ssqltable;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(Common.connectionstring);

            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sclearsql, sqlconn);

            sqlconn.Open();
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlconn.Close();

            OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring);
            OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(myexceldataquery, oledbconn);
            oledbconn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
            SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(Common.connectionstring);
            bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = ssqltable;

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
            }

            dr.Close();
            oledbconn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { throw ex; }
}
```

That code is really have an error if I add the PODATE, PORECEIVEDDATE and DELIVERDATE. All I just want is to get the 3 remaining parameters value from Excel into the database.

I don't want to change the template in Excel because of some reason.

Please I badly need your help guys. I really appreciate it.

Comment: It looks like the podate is in a separate table below. This won't work unless you tidy up the format of the Excel document

Comment: so there is really no way to aim wait i want? how about a code that will locate the value of a specific cell and get the value of the next row cell?

Comment: You need to separate out those 2 tables in the template. You might be able to say something a bit like select from Sheet1!a1:z5. And then a select from Sheet1!a15:d20. You obviously have a different number of rows to handle, but there is a small chance it works. Otherwise I'm stuck on this 1